# How to find lat/lon values for every pixel in a GeoTIFF file?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, postgis-2.0

I want to a store GeoTIFF file pixel by pixel in the database. I need to store pixel values along with the lat/lon of that pixel on the GeoTIFF image. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Is the goal to be able to query by Lat/Lon?  You could accomplish this with GDAL using the geotransform attribute - I can provide a python example.  The conversion could be pre-rendered into a 2 band geotiff (Band1 - LAT, Band2 - LON), but I wonder if it wouldn't be more efficient to do this on the fly.  I guess a use case would help.

Answer (score 13):

In a generic sense, use the [affine transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) parameters, which should be available with any raster file format. With GDAL, this is available with [GetGeoTransform()](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#af9593cc241e7d140f5f3c4798a43a668), or PostGIS' [ST_GeoReference()](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_GeoReference.html) function. After finding these six parameters, one only needs to determine which ones they are, then a function can be made to transform in linear space.

E.g., with Python:

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('myfile.tif')

# unravel GDAL affine transform parameters
c, a, b, f, d, e = ds.GetGeoTransform()

def pixel2coord(col, row):
    """Returns global coordinates to pixel center using base-0 raster index"""
    xp = a * col + b * row + a * 0.5 + b * 0.5 + c
    yp = d * col + e * row + d * 0.5 + e * 0.5 + f
    return(xp, yp)
```

For example, if there is a pixel at col=10, row=22, then the real-world coordinates to the pixel center are:

```
>>> pixel2coord(10, 22)
(2780000.0, 6162300.0)
```

Something similar can be cooked up for PostGIS with [ST_Affine()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Affine.html).

Answer (score 2):

The world file (.tfw) that accompanies a GeoTIFF contains:

- pixel size in the x-direction (and y-direction) in map units/pixel and
- x-coordinate (and y-coordinate) of the center of the upper left pixel.
  This is all you need to calculate position in Lat/Lon of every pixel.

Comment: In addition to what you describe, at a minimum you need to know the coordinate system!  (A world file does not include such information.)

Comment: Also, not every GeoTIFF contains a world file. A [true GeoTIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF) has the coordinate information stored in the header, not in a separate file. However, the term "GeoTIFF" is often applied to TIFF images with a world file. The point is, there won't always be a TFW.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit archaic:
Convert the pixels to points, add lat and long fields, and populate with lat and long values.