# OGR create polygon giving four corners from raster pixel position

Tags: python, gdal, geometry, ogr, numpy

How do I create a geometry from pixels positions in GeoTiff?

```
ds = gdal.Open("image.tif")
myarray = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
shape = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
```

And let's say I would like to add points to the ring for a polygon from the raster based on x, y position from the raster... like:

```
shape.AddPoint(<myarray[100][100]>) # where myarray[100,100] are pixel positions from myarray
...
shape.AddPoint(<myarray[100][100]>)
geom = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
geom.AddGeometry(shape)
```

Comment: I personally don't understand what you mean by `<myarray[100][100]>, <myarray[200][200]>`.  Position is defined by (x, y). That means there are two positions in `AddPoint` method -> `AddPoint((x, y), (x, y))`. However, it should be `AddPoint(x, y)`.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz yes, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this script will solve your problem. ([Reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/59950/29431))

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
import numpy as np

raster_file = "image.tif"
ds = gdal.Open(raster_file)
c, a, b, f, d, e = ds.GetGeoTransform()

def p(col, row): #p: pixel coords to map coords
    x_geo = a * col + b * row + a * 0.5 + b * 0.5 + c
    y_geo = d * col + e * row + d * 0.5 + e * 0.5 + f
    return (x_geo, y_geo) # map coordinates

shape = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
shape.AddPoint(*p(100, 100)) # 100, 100: pixel coordinates
shape.AddPoint(*p(100, 200))
shape.AddPoint(*p(200, 200))
shape.AddPoint(*p(200, 100))
shape.AddPoint(*p(100, 100))

geom = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
geom.AddGeometry(shape)
```